# In French, how do you idiomatically say "a one-to-one mix"?

Tags: expressions

> **A one-to-one mix** of coffee and milk, with foam on top.

In conversation, I wanted to express this idea in French. I'm looking for the French equivalent of "a one-to-one mix (of ...)" in the sense of "**half** coffee (and) **half** milk".

Answer (score 5):

Dans la vie de tous les jours, on dit « moitié café, moitié lait » ou « un mélange moitié café, moitié lait » ou « un mélange moitié-moitié de café et de lait » ou « un mélange de café et de lait, moitié-moitié », suivant le degré de verbosité voulu.

Dans un contexte plus formel, et même souvent dans les recettes de cuisine, on écrit « un mélange à parts égales de café et de lait ».

Pour d'autres fractions on écrit en général « une part de X, deux parts de Y » ou « une part de X et deux parts de Y » ou « une part de X pour deux parts de Y ». On peut aussi un peu moins formellement dire « un mélange deux tiers-un tiers de café et de lait » ou « un mélange (de) deux tiers de café (et) un tiers de lait ».

Comment: Je ne m'attendais pas à ce qu'il y ait autant de variantes. « Moitié café, moitié lait » est la première phrase qui me soit venue à l'esprit. « Un mélange à parts égales de X et de Y» me semble un choix idéal pour "a one-to-one mix".

Comment: On peut ajouter: **mi-café, mi-lait**.

Comment: J'allais écrire une réponse pour rajouter "une part X, une part Y", j'ai bien fait de lire jusqu'au bout ^^

Comment: je suis presque sûr d'avoir aussi déjà rencontré la forme `mélange un pour un`

Comment: @Flying_whale `mélange un pour un` et ses déclinaisons (`deux pour un`, `trois pour deux`) sont très communs au Québec. Incertain de leur fréquence ailleurs dans la Francophonie, mais confirmation tout au moins pour le Canada francophone.